# Java with MongoDB connection issues - getting SQL exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, sqlexception

New here, first post... I am trying to connect to MongoDB using Spring Boot but getting `sqlexception`... Any suggestions? Why I get SQL exceptions in MongoDB configuration?

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {



    @Bean
    --------public MongoItemReader<MongoDBEntity> reader() {
        System.out.println("REader");
        MongoItemReader<MongoDBEntity> reader = new ----------MongoItemReader<MongoDBEntity>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setQuery("{}");
        reader.setTargetType(MongoDBEntity.class);
        ---------reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends MongoDBEntity>) MongoDBEntity.class);
        reader.setSort(new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>() {
            {
                put("_id", Direction.ASC);
            }
        });
        return reader;

    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<MongoDBEntity> writer() {
        System.out.println("Writer");
        FlatFileItemWriter<MongoDBEntity> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<MongoDBEntity>();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(
                "c://outputs//temp.all.csv"));
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<MongoDBEntity>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MongoDBEntity>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "name" });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<MongoDBEntity, MongoDBEntity> chunk(10).reader(reader())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end()
                .build();
    }

----------  @Bean
    public CustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(Collections.emptyList());
    }

}
```

Is there anything I am missing... Why I am getting SQL exception in Mongo? Checked the pom file... No references to Oracle etc...

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Without your exception message (and stack if possible) it will be difficult for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys .. sorry it my mistake that while creating the file i used previous pom file which had some references. once after removing them and right version mongo jars fixed the issue.

thanks again..